# Using a gear-styled wiper in a potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer, enclosure, cases, plastic

I want to use a custom Gear styled wiper in a regular potentiometer.
I found an old product that uses this. It has some weird plastic contraption in order to achieve this.

I supply some pictures for further clarification:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know something about this way of controlling the potentiometer?

Answer (score 2):

It just looks like a thumbwheel rotating in a plastic bushing. Easy-peasy and cheap if you are injection molding the parts, and certainly possible with 3D printing (though perhaps not ideal with FDM rather than SLA).

The square protrusion mates with a matching hole in the open carbon pot or trimpot. If you don't feel like gambling with poorly specified stampings, some makers (eg. Piher) make pots that are intended for this kind of application.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please post a link with those pots? I don't know where to find them the ones exactly you mention or how to search for them...

Comment: Also, i saw some examples after searching for thumbwheel potentiometer. Is it easy to install your own thumbwheel, or embed the thumbwheel in the plastic housing?

Comment: You would make the thumbwheel and the housing, by whatever means makes sense for the quantities and budget you have. I gave you a manufacturer name, which you can search and there are probably others that are suitable, looking for those and determining which is best for the application is your job.

Comment: What I was trying to say was this: If you look at the first picture, with the plastic mechanism.... If you happen to have any experience in this kind of design... Do you know how that mechanism manages to stay in place? Have you designed something like this in the past?

Comment: Plastic Part Design for Injection Molding: An Introduction by Robert A. Malloy is a good general reference.  Bayer (the plastic resin manufacturer) has a good reference on design of snap fit components. But they're for injection molding rather than 3D printing and that's not really something you dip into casually, the tool design and fabrication costs and minimum quantities are substantial. Hobbyists have their own approaches for 3D printed parts which are far more accessible where only a few are to be made.

Comment: I was considering buying a home injection molding machine (Buster Beagle). So that mechanism is a snap-fit mechanism. That was the thing I needed. One last thing. Do you know how this is consisted? It looks like the tumbwheel, the long lateral axis, the two circular things that are visible. I cannot take it apart, so I don't know what is connected to what and if a part is a union with another part. Have you seen this design before? It looks like glue was used, but since I cannot distinguish the parts, I don't know what is going on.

Comment: The gap suggests a snap fit to me, but if you take it apart you should be able to see mold split lines, witness marks from ejector pins and slides and so on. It could be all snap, there could be adhesive, or heat sealing or ultrasonic welding. Lots of possibilities, but all sadly quite off-topic here.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot take it apart without destroying it. When you say mold split lines, you mean it was molded in one all together, along with the overall enclosure? Or molded separated, then fused with the enclosure?